# Display columns dynamically in a BI Publisher report based on the parameter value selected

Tags: oracle, rtf, erp, bi-publisher

The report has AR balance amount which is bucketed by days (0-30 days,30-60 days, etc)

The requirement is to have a parameter for Bucket and the values should be 180+,210+,240+

When 180+ is selected for the parameter, the report should display columns

> 0-30,30-60,60-90,90-120,120-150,150-180,180+

When 210+ is selected for the parameter, the report should display columns

> 0-30,30-60,60-90,90-120,120-150,150-180,180-210,210+

When 240+ is selected for the parameter, the report should display columns

> 0-30,30-60,60-90,90-120,120-150,150-180,180-210,210-240,240+

I know how to populate the amount into diff buckets but not sure how to dynamically control bucketing based on the parameter value selected.